# Can someone help me understand how to allocate properly in c?

Tags: c, memory-management

I don't think I properly understand how to allocate memory for what I want to do.

I would like my program to store arguments from the command line into an array of stucts called Command which has char **args in it.  for example if I run

```
./test.c echo hello : ls -l
```

I want it to store it as this

```
commands[0].args[0]= echo
commands[0].args[1]= hello
commands[1].args[0]= ls
commands[1].args[1]= -l
```

But instead my code is storing it in this way

```
commands[0].args[0]= echo
commands[0].args[1]= hello
commands[0].args[2]= ls
commands[0].args[3]= -l
commands[1].args[0]= ls
commands[1].args[1]= -l
```

Could someone help me understand why it is storing ls -l in 2 places?  Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test {
   char **args;
} Command;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i, j, k;
   Command *commands;

   j = k = 0;
   commands = (Command *)malloc(argc * sizeof(Command));

   for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
   {
      if (strcmp(argv[i], ":") == 0)
      {
         j++;
         k = 0;
      }
      else {
         commands[j].args = (char **)realloc(commands[j].args, (k+1) * sizeof(char*));
         commands[j].args[k++] = argv[i];
      }
   }

   for (i = 0; i <= j; i++)
   {
      for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
      {
         printf("commands[%d].args[%d]= %s\n", i, k, commands[i].args[k]);
      }
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)` is undefined behavior

Comment: You cannot `realloc` something you haven't allocated previously (or set to NULL). But that's what you do for `commands[j].args`.

Comment: I figured out that commands[0].args[2] and commands[1].args[0] are the same address...  How can I fix/change this?

Comment: commands[0].args[2] was never allocated in your initial code.  By lucky coincidence, space for commands[1] was allocated immediately after commands[0].  So, when you tried to look beyond the bounds of commands[0].args, you happened to print out commands[1].args[0]. This is undefined behavior!  The problem is that you are trying to look at a nonexistent array member commands[0].args[2].  Use the advice below to limit your printing for loop to the actual length of each command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would allocate the memory:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cmd_s {
    int num;
    char **args;
} cmd_t;

void print_cmds(cmd_t *c, int num) {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0;i<=num;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<c[i].num;j++)
            printf("cmds[%d][%d] = %s\n", i, j,c[i].args[j]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, j = 0, k = 0;
    cmd_t *cmds;

    cmds = (cmd_t *)malloc(sizeof(cmd_t));
    cmds[0].args = NULL;
    cmds[0].num = 0;

    for (i=1;i<argc;i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], ":") == 0) {
            cmds = (cmd_t *)realloc(cmds, (sizeof(cmd_t) * ++j) + 1);
            cmds[j].args = NULL;
            cmds[j].num = 0;
            continue;
        }
        cmds[j].args = (char **)realloc(cmds[j].args, sizeof(char *) * ++cmds[j].num);
        cmds[j].args[cmds[j].num-1] = (char *)malloc(50);
        strcpy(cmds[j].args[cmds[j].num-1], argv[i]);
    }

    print_cmds(cmds, j);

    for (i=0;i<=j;i++) {
        for(k=0;k<cmds[i].num;k++)
            free(cmds[i].args[k]);
        free(cmds[i].args);
    }

    free(cmds);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when i ran with ./test.c echo hello how are you : ls -l .  It stored ls -l how are you in the second command.  I found that was due to cmds[0].args[2] and cmds[1].arsg[2] being the same address..  How can I fix this?

Comment: cmds[1].args[2] is outside the bounds of the array.  You should have the following values at the end of the run:  cmds[1].num = 2; cmds[1].args[0] = "ls"; cmds[1].args[1] = "-l".  Args is an array of length 2, so it's behavior for elements other than cmds[1].args[0] and cmds[2].args[1] is UNDEFINED.  The C standard does not guarantee behavior for cmds[2].args[<2-...>].  You should never try to access cmds[1].args[2], cmds[1].args[3], etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your data storage structure has no way of telling how many strings in `commands[j]` are valid.  So I think it's putting two pointers each in `commands[0]` and `commands[1]` just like you expect.  But then your print loop looks at `commands[0].args[k]` for k all the way up to 4, even though it's only valid to look at the first two.  When you get up to looking at `commands[0].args[2]`, the result is undefined.  (Showing memory from somewhere else in your program, crashing, and catching fire are just a few of the things a program is allowed to do if you use undefined behavior.)

To figure out how many arguments are in each command, you could add a counter member to your `struct test`.  Or maybe allocate one more pointer than there are arguments, and put a NULL after the last argument.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your `Command` structs only have one `arg`

Perhaps you should consider

```
typedef struct test {
   char **args[5];
} Command;
```

and then design a better data structure, like a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should store the length of args in the struct?

```
typedef struct test {
    char ** args;
    unsigned length;
} Command;
```

Also, maybe you should consider using some of the built in functionality of the C string library.  For example, [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) splits a string using the delimiters you give it.